# Why isn't my Lottie file appearing in my project?

Tags: ios, swift, lottie

I'm trying to use Lottie files in my project; I have tried many way but none of them work... nothing appears.

I tried two ways:

1. `lottieAnimation()`
2. `setupAnimation()`

I also tried through UIView.

```swift
import UIKit
import Lottie

class BonusVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var containerAnim: UIView!
    var animation : AnimationView?
    let animationView = AnimationView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        lottieAnimation()
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        lottieAnimation()
        //setupAnimation()
    }
    
    
    func setupAnimation() {
        animation = AnimationView(name: "wallet")
        animation?.frame = self.containerAnim.frame
        self.containerAnim.addSubview(animation!)
        animation?.loopMode = .autoReverse
        animation?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        animation?.play()
    }
    
    func lottieAnimation() {
        let animation = Animation.named("wifi", subdirectory: "LottieAnimation")
        animationView.animation = animation
        animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        view.addSubview(animationView)
        
        animationView.backgroundBehavior = .pauseAndRestore
        animationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        animationView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        animationView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        animationView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
        animationView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        animationView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.fittingSizeLevel, for: .horizontal)
        animationView.play()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it helpful to begin with a simple proof of concept to make sure that things are working correctly and then I customize from there. Try this code with one of the example Lottie Files:

```
import UIKit
import Lottie

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let testAnimation = "bb8"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func showAnimation(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let animationView = AnimationView()
        let animation = Animation.named(testAnimation)
        animationView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 350)
        animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        animationView.animation = animation
        animationView.loopMode = .loop

        self.view.addSubview(animationView)

        animationView.play()
    }
}
```

bb8 is the name of the JSON file. I am using Swift Package Manager to bring in Lottie-ios, but this also works with CocoaPods.